# Seeking SSD for MacBook that doesn't create problems when unplugged

Tags: ssd

I have [this SSD](https://shop.westerndigital.com/products/portable-drives/sandisk-extreme-pro-usb-3-1-ssd#SDSSDE80-1T00-A25)

[image]

Sometimes I inadvertently unplug it, or the MacBook runs out of battery when I'm not watching and powers down. And then it is a completely random process to get it to show up again. Maybe requiring several reboots and prayer.

Is this an inherent problem with USB SSDs on MacOS?  Or is it particular to this manufacturer?
Has anyone had good experience with a particular USB SSD?

Comment: Unplugging a USB-attached drive without unmounting it first through the OS, or a power loss without unmounting it, has a high chance of causing problems with any drive of any make on any operating system. I'd suggest a change in the way you use that computer to prevent that from occurring.And, since a MacBook has an internal battery, how does unplugging power result in its shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

Such random reboots are caused very often by a power supply problem.

Hard disks (incl. SSDs) require a lot of power, at least to the limitations of the USB: it is at most 2A, 5V = 10W. Disks can require 20W or more.

Try to connect it through an USB hub with external power supply, but so that only your SSD uses it. If so it works, problem found (possibly solved).

Side remark: The problem can be caused also by an *other* buggy USB device connected to an *other* USB port of your laptop. In most cases, USB ports get the power from a common power source, and a short circuit or other current waster, caused by most likely LQ power adapters inside your *other* USB devices, can harm also the power supply of your SSD.